# Do they sell powdered alcohol as a premix drink?

Tags: spirits, alcohol, palcohol

In the past there have been attempts to launch alcohol powder as a premix for human consumption (ie. rum flavored powder, all you need is a coke to transform in into a cuba libre).

Does anyone know if any company is manufacturing or willing to for commercial purposes?
Palcohol was one that got close but never took off. They never gave proof of their alcohol powder being effective.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**Do they sell powdered alcohol as a premix drink?**

The short answer is **yes**, but it is not being sold at present. Latter half of my answer shows how to make your own palcohol at home. It is so easy, so why pay for the extras!

First of all, **palcohol** was created by a gentleman by the name of Mark Phillips.

The US federal government approved Palcohol on March 10, 2015 and it is now legal to be sold in the United States. However it will not be for sale immediately but possibly in late 2021 at the earliest. I doubt it will ever make it to market, but that is me.

Palcohol, when used as directed, by adding six ounces of liquid to it, is equal to a standard mixed drink.

> What flavors are there? We plan on releasing five versions sold in a pouch that is the equivalent to one shot of alcohol:
>
> - V which is powder made from premium vodka distilled four times.
> - R which is powder made from premium Puerto Rican rum
>
> V and R can be used two ways. One way is by adding six ounces of your favorite mixer to make a Rum and Coke, Vodka and Orange Juice, etc. Another option is adding six ounces of water to the powder and then adding a flavored drink powder to make it any flavor you want. The result is equivalent to one average mixed drink.
>
> The three cocktail versions are:
>
> - **Cosmopolitan**
> - **Powderita** - tastes just like a Margarita
> - **Lemon Drop**
>
> Just add water to these three flavors for an instant cocktail. - [**Palcohol is Powered Alcohol**](https://palcohol.com/)

Mark Philips from Scottsdale, AZ. explains what palcohol is in his YouTube video: [**The Truth About Palcohol**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1002&v=LYP085QJvtk&feature=emb_logo)

**Addendum:**

You can always make your own. It is so simple you do not need to wait any longer!

On [***Popular Science's***](https://www.popsci.com/article/technology/how-make-powdered-booze-home/) website, Paul Adams wrote that he didn’t know how Palcohol did it but he explained how he could make powdered alcohol at home using a specially modified starch - a [maltodextrin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltodextrin) made from tapioca and sold under the brand name N-Zorbit M.

[image: Maltodextrin and Rum]

In the right ratio, N-Zorbit M powder can fully soak up the alcohol and still remain powdery.

For an example, Adams suggested drizzling 30 grams of high-proof (150- to 190-proof) alcohol into a mixing bowl containing 100 grams of N-Zorbit M while whisking steadily. You can then either sift it though a fine sieve or just use a blender to begin with.

Done properly, he says, you end up with strong soluble alcohol.

No need to limit yourself to rum or vodka. Any strong alcoholic liquor will do, including [whiskey, tequila, gin and absinthe](https://flaviar.com/blog/strongest-spirits-on-the-market).

Ps. If you do make it yourself in any large quantities make sure to keep it in individual airtight freezer bags and depending on when you intend to use them store them in your fridge or deep-freezer.